# WordPress: Softaclous - Could not write the Configuration File _htaccess

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am trying to install WordPress on my parent domain in public_html directory. it gives me this every time I try to install.

I tried to delete htaccess as well, changed permissions but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: what's the permission now ? and make sure you are using same account , for ex if it belongs to root account then don't try to change permission through another user account , would be better if you change permission through sudo chmod command

Comment: @ShantunParmar I did that before, I am doing a fresh installation with the same account. and it doesn't work now. and if I change permission to write in htaccess file. it gets reverted to normal if I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and my issue was resolved by changing public_html folder permission to write.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced a similar issue but just edited my file permission for the .htaccess file and try reinstalling WordPress.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome! Please be more precise.